# Able to save data without filling inlines even when required fields are there in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have 3 models Course, Course Details and Course Deadlines
models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    info= models.TextField()

class CourseDetails(models.Model):
    course=models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING)
    info= models.TextField()

class CourseDeadlines(models.Model):
    course=models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING)
    date= models.DateTimeField()
```

admin.py

```
class CourseDetailsInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model=CourseDetails
    extra=0
    max_num=1
    can_delete= False

class CourseDeadlinesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model=CourseDeadlines
    extra=0
    max_num=1
    can_delete= False

class CoursesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[CourseDetailsInline,CourseDeadlinesInline]

admin.site.register(Course,CoursesAdmin)
```

I am able to save the course without having to fill the inline fields even though they are required fields.

Comment: How are they required fields? I don't see anything in your code to set that up ...

Comment: add required = True to your model fields.

Comment: @ariaman5 THat won't work because they are not model fields on `Course`. It's a FK to `Course` from the other models. Some constraints are needed, but I'm unclear on what's already there, since OP indicates they should be required already.

Comment: @ariaman5 that is an example that i posted... but I have the fields are blank=False, null=False in actual data for all the fields that are required. Course Details and Course Deadlines are child tables. I am showing them as inlines in django. I am able to save the form without having to add anything in these inlines. But I want to makesure the data gets saved only when the required fields in the inlines are also filled.